# Resetear variable estatica heredada

Tags: php, poo, static

estoy empezando a aprender POO en PHP, cree 2 clases Persona y Estudiante para probar. Tengo una variable estatica 'size' que se incremente cada vez que se crea un objeto para sumar el numero de objetos creados, herede esta clase Persona a Estudiante pero al momento de hacerlo Estudiante toma el numero de Personas. Por ejemplo si creo 1 persona y 1 estudiante me da 3 personas y estudiantes en total.

```
class Persona{
    public static $size;
    public $nombre;
    public $apellido;
    public $edad;
    public $genero;
    

    public function __construct($nombre, $apellido, $edad, $genero)
    {
      $this->nombre = $nombre;
      $this->apellido = $apellido;
      $this->edad = $edad;
      $this->genero = $genero;
      self::$size++;
      echo 'Personas = '.self::$size;
    }
      
    class Estudiante extends Persona{

    public $colegio;
    public $curso;
    public $especialidad;

    public function __construct($nombre, $apellido, $edad, $genero, $colegio, $curso, $especialidad)
    {
      parent::__construct($nombre, $apellido, $edad, $genero);
      $this->nombre = $nombre;
      $this->apellido = $apellido;
      $this->edad = $edad;
      self::$size++;
      echo 'Estudiantes = '.self::$size;
    }
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer unico el valor de la variable estatica heredada para que no tome en cuenta el valor de la clase padre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que ocurre en tu código es lo lógico y lo correcto.

Si observas bien, cuando se crean instancias de `Estudiante` es llamado el constructor del padre: `parent::__construct($nombre, $apellido, $edad, $genero);` y en dicho constructor ocurre el incremento de `$size` **sin diferenciar nada**:  `self::$size++;`

Si la intención es tener un conteo por separado de las instancias de `Persona` por un lado y de `Estudiante` por otro, tendrías que implementar esa diferenciación de alguna forma.

Por ejemplo, podrías declarar en `Persona` un array con dos claves: `Persona` y `Estudiante`, con valores iniciales equivalentes a `0`. Este array sustituiría a `$size`, por claridad en la convención de nombre podrías nombrarlo `$counter` o algo parecido:

```
public static $counter=array("Persona"=>0,"Estudiante"=>0);
```

Luego, en el constructor de `Persona`, sumas uno al índice respectivo usando `get_class()`:

```
self::$counter[get_class($this)]+=1;
```

Haciendo eso, `$counter` irá sumando por separado las instancias de `Persona` y de `Estudiante`.

El código final quedaría así:

#### `Persona`

```
class Persona{
    public static $counter=array("Persona"=>0,"Estudiante"=>0);
    public $nombre;
    public $apellido;
    public $edad;
    public $genero;
    

    public function __construct($nombre, $apellido, $edad, $genero)
    {
      $this->nombre = $nombre;
      $this->apellido = $apellido;
      $this->edad = $edad;
      $this->genero = $genero;
      self::$counter[get_class($this)]+=1;
    }
}
```

#### `Estudiante`

```
class Estudiante extends Persona{

    public $colegio;
    public $curso;
    public $especialidad;

    public function __construct($nombre, $apellido, $edad, $genero, $colegio, $curso, $especialidad)
    {
      parent::__construct($nombre, $apellido, $edad, $genero);
      $this->nombre = $nombre;
      $this->apellido = $apellido;
      $this->edad = $edad;
    }
}
```

Si creas dos instancias de `Persona` y una de `Estudiante`, la estructura de `$counter` sería esta:

```
array(2) {
  ["Persona"]=>
  int(2)
  ["Estudiante"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Y para saber cuántas instancias hay de cada uno harías algo así:

```
#$mInstance sería una instancia válida de cualquiera de tus clases
echo "Total Persona: ".$mInstance::$counter["Persona"].PHP_EOL;
echo "Total Estudiante: ".$mInstance::$counter["Estudiante"];
```

**Salida:**

```
Total Persona: 2
Total Estudiante: 1
```

### PD

Otro modo de hacerlo sería ir contando por separado en cada clase, pero eso ya depende de lo que quieras hacer realmente. Si en algún escenario conviene tener el conteo global de objetos entonces es mejor mantener un contador basado en la herencia y a su vez diferenciado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me di cuenta totalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacer que `$size` sea `private` en ambas clases así no se hereda, y para no hacer copy paste en cada `extends` definir un [`trait`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php).

```php
<?php
trait cuentaSize{
  private static $size;
  public static function getSize(){
    return self::$size;
  }
}

class Persona{
  use cuentaSize;
  public $nombre;
  public $apellido;
  public $edad;
  public $genero;

  public function __construct(
    $nombre, $apellido, $edad, $genero
  ){
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
    $this->apellido = $apellido;
    $this->edad = $edad;
    $this->genero = $genero;
    self::$size++;
    $className = static::class;
    echo "nueva Persona desde new {$className}({$this->nombre}), ";
    echo "size = " . self::$size . PHP_EOL;
  }
}  

class Estudiante extends Persona{
  use cuentaSize;
  public $colegio;
  public $curso;
  public $especialidad;

  public function __construct(
    $nombre, $apellido, $edad, $genero, $colegio, $curso, $especialidad
  ){
    parent::__construct($nombre, $apellido, $edad, $genero);
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
    $this->apellido = $apellido;
    $this->edad = $edad;
    self::$size++;
    $className = static::class;
    echo "* nuevo Estudiante desde new {$className}({$this->nombre}), ";
    echo "size = " . self::$size . PHP_EOL;
  }
}

class Profesor extends Persona{
  use cuentaSize;
  // incrementar el size no heredado en el construct así no queda en 0
  // pasamos los mismos argumentos al constructor padre
  // php >= 5.6
  public function __construct( ...$args ) {
    parent::__construct( ...$args );
    self::$size++;
    $className = static::class;
    echo "** nuevo Profesor desde new {$className}({$this->nombre}), "
    echo "size = " . self::$size . PHP_EOL;
  }
}

$P1 = new Persona( 'NombrePersona1', 'A1', 'e1', 'g1');
$P2 = new Persona( 'NombrePersona2', 'A2', 'e2', 'g2');

$E1 = new Estudiante( 'NombreEstudiante1', 'Ae1', 'e1', 'g1', 'co1', 'cu1', 'es1');
$E2 = new Estudiante( 'NombreEstudiante2', 'Ae2', 'e2', 'g2', 'co2', 'cu2', 'es2');
$E3 = new Estudiante( 'NombreEstudiante3', 'Ae3', 'e3', 'g3', 'co3', 'cu3', 'es3');

$Pr1 = new Profesor( 'NombreProfesor1', 'A1', 'e1', 'g1');
$Pr2 = new Profesor( 'NombreProfesor2', 'A2', 'e2', 'g2');

echo 'Size Personas: ' . Persona::getSize() . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Size Estudiantes: ' . Estudiante::getSize() . PHP_EOL;

echo sprintf(
    'Hemos creado %d personas de las cuales %d son estudiantes, y %d profesores.',
    Persona::getSize(),
    Estudiante::getSize(),
    Profesor::getSize()
) . PHP_EOL;
```

salida

```
nueva Persona desde new Persona(NombrePersona1), size = 1
nueva Persona desde new Persona(NombrePersona2), size = 2
nueva Persona desde new Estudiante(NombreEstudiante1), size = 3
* nuevo Estudiante desde new Estudiante(NombreEstudiante1), size = 1
nueva Persona desde new Estudiante(NombreEstudiante2), size = 4
* nuevo Estudiante desde new Estudiante(NombreEstudiante2), size = 2
nueva Persona desde new Estudiante(NombreEstudiante3), size = 5
* nuevo Estudiante desde new Estudiante(NombreEstudiante3), size = 3
nueva Persona desde new Profesor(NombreProfesor1), size = 6
** nuevo Profesor desde new Profesor(NombreProfesor1), size = 1
nueva Persona desde new Profesor(NombreProfesor2), size = 7
** nuevo Profesor desde new Profesor(NombreProfesor2), size = 2
Size Personas: 7
Size Estudiantes: 3
Hemos creado 7 personas de las cuales 3 son estudiantes, y 2 profesores.
```